# What is this effect called and how to execute it?

Tags: photoshop-effects, tools, free

What is this effect called and
what is the best free online tool to use to achieve this effect?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't you like the results? We are not a tutorial-on-demand site, please show us some effort.

Comment: i need free online tools. I can easily do this in PS or something. But i need something like generator for this effect

Comment: If you could replicate this easily in Photoshop, you should be able to do it in GIMP or Paint.NET, too. They are free.

Comment: Please [edit] that information into your question. Comments are temporary and will ultimately be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

This effect is called a **kaleidoscope effect** (or [Busby Berkeley effect](https://ask.metafilter.com/91071/Busby-Berkeley-Effect) in film). To add to user287001's comment, GIMP and Paint.net are great free options if you're comfortable using Photoshop. Another app you can check out is called [PicsArt](https://picsart.com/blog/post/how-to-kaleidoscope-effect-picsart-photo-editor/), which has a pretty specific tutorial on the [kaleidescope effect here](https://picsart.com/blog/post/how-to-kaleidoscope-effect-picsart-photo-editor/). Here's a few more examples if you search this term on Google:

[image]
*The Busby Berkeley effect as utilized in **42nd Street** (c.1933)*

[image]
*Marina Diamandis, from Marina and the Diamonds, shot by Tokion for Factory.*

[image]
*Kaleidoscope effect from the aforementioned PicsArt tutorial*

Comment: Hi zeethreepio. Can I draw your attention to [this discussion](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/what-to-do-with-tutorial-requests-part-ii) on meta? We are trying to decrease the amount of lazy 'tutorial-on-demand' questions on the site, and one of the early signs is that answering them isn't a good idea. I'd appreciate your input on the matter. Thanks!